# Supremum of two continuous functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

Trying to check my answer for this question:

Let $f,g$ be continous real functions in closed interval $[a,b]$, such that $\forall x\in [a,b], f(x)>g(x)$.
Then $\sup f([a,b])>\sup g([a,b])$.

It seems obviously true — unless someone would come up with a surprising counter-example I have not seen yet.

This is my proof:
Since $f,g$ are both continuous in $[a,b]$, according to the extreme value theorem, $\exists c\in[a,b], f(c)=\max f([a,b])=\sup f([a,b])$ , and also $\exists d\in[a,b], g(d)=\max g([a,b])=\sup g([a,b])$.

So, ultimately:
$f(c)\geq f(d)>g(d)$ and it's settled. Right?

I could also use the definition of the supremum with $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists x\in[a,b]$ such that $ f(x)>\sup f([a,b])-\epsilon$ after showing its existence with the EVT, but it all goes down to that same inequality.

Am I right?

Comment: It seems fine for me. In my opinion, one should use the notation $\max_{x\in [a, b]} f(x)$ instead of $\max f([a, b])$.

Comment: @ntt. $f([a,b])$ would normally denote the set $\{f(x): x\in [a,b]\}$ so $\max f([a,b])$ is consistent  but $\max_{x\in [a,b]}$ is my preference too.

Comment: You can also note that $f-g$ is  positive and continuous on $[a,b]$ so it has a positive minimum value $ m.$  So if $x\in [a,b]$ and  $f(x)=\sup_{x\in [a,b]}$ then  for all $y\in  [a,b]$ we have $f(x)-m\geq f(y)-m\geq g(y).$

Comment: Where f achieves its supremum, g achieves even more. Thus the supremum of g is still more.